# error realloc 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, realloc

I would like to realloc a 2D array. I have a `counter`, `itime` it increases each step. Each step, I would like to reallocate my array, keeping the old values, and add new values to the array. When `itime=1`, I use only `malloc`, because it is allocated for the first time. When `itime` increases (e.q. `itime=2`), `realloc` is used. In the realloc process my GUI crashes.

Can somebody tell me the reason of the crash, Have I reallocated correctly?

```
int itime;
char ** solpointer;

for( itime = 1 ; itime <= 4 ; itime++ ) {
    if( itime == 1 ) {
        solpointer = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * itime);
        solpointer[itime-1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 32);
    }
    else {
        solpointer = (char**)realloc(solpointer, sizeof(char*) * itime);
        solpointer[itime-1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning you can simply make sure `solpointer` is initially `NULL` and throw out the if-1 special case. `realloc` acts like `malloc` when the passed address is NULL. And I would *strongly* advise you validate the result of *either* before assuming they worked. Finally, the casts are not needed. if your code whines with them omitted it you're likely forgetting to include `stdlib.h`, which will cause havoc if you're compiling this on a 64-bit platform with 32-bit `int`s. Now, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: check for `malloc` or `realloc` returning `NULL`, and make sure you have got `#include <stdlib.h>`